# OSGi/Equinox Classloader uses unexpected Bundle Version

Tags: java, osgi, classloader, equinox

I have an OSGI application with Bundles requiring 2 version of IBM MQSeries : 
6.0.2 and 7.0.1.
We installed the following IBM MQ Bundles (just mentionning the main ones)

- `com.ibm.mq.osgi.client_6.0.2.5.jar`
- `com.ibm.msg.client.osgi.wmq_7.0.1.5.jar`

We defined our 2 Bundles to Require-Bundle as follows (yes I know, we should use import-package ;-))
Bundle A `Require-Bundle: com.ibm.msg.client.osgi.wmq;bundle-version="7.0.1"`

Bundle B `Require-Bundle: com.ibm.mq.osgi.client;bundle-version="[6.0.2,7.0.0)"`

We define additionally `org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation=javax.*`.
No buddy class loading, no Dynamic Class loading.

Now, when Bundle A loads the `com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory` using

```
final MQQueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
```

I would expect Equinox to load the class from the Bundle `com.ibm.msg.client.osgi.wmq_7.0.1.5`. 
This is NOT the case !?!?? The MQQueueConnectionFactory is loaded from Bundle `com.ibm.mq.osgi.client_6.0.2.5` !!

As consequence, Bundle A is using MQ 6.0.2.5..

Setting some Equinox Debug options, I can see the following :

```
Bundle id 56 == com.ibm.mq.osgi.client_6.0.2.5
Bundle id 53 == com.ibm.msg.client.osgi.jms.prereq_7.0.1.5

[...]
BundleLoader[A_1.1.3].loadBundleClass(com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory)
BundleLoader[com.ibm.mq.osgi.client_6.0.2.5].findLocalClass(com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory)
BundleClassLoader[PATH/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/56/1/.cp/com.ibm.mq.jar].findClassImpl(com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory)
BundleClassLoader[PATH/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/56/1/.cp/com.ibm.mqjms.jar].findClassImpl(com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory)
  about to read 11659 bytes from com/ibm/mq/jms/MQQueueConnectionFactory.class
  read 11659 bytes from PATH/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/56/1/.cp/com.ibm.mqjms.jar/com/ibm/mq/jms/MQQueueConnectionFactory.class
  defining class com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory
[...]
```

The "funny" part being that the javax.jms.* classes are loaded from  `com.ibm.msg.client.osgi.jms.prereq_7.0.1.5`

```
BundleClassLoader[com.ibm.mq.osgi.client_6.0.2.5].loadClass(javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory)
BundleLoader[com.ibm.mq.osgi.client_6.0.2.5].loadBundleClass(javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory)
BundleLoader[com.ibm.msg.client.osgi.jms.prereq_7.0.1.5].findLocalClass(javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory)
BundleClassLoader[PATH/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/53/1/.cp/jms.jar].findClassImpl(javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory)
  about to read 371 bytes from javax/jms/QueueConnectionFactory.class
  read 371 bytes from /opt/fxportal/FXMB/application/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/53/1/.cp/jms.jar/javax/jms/QueueConnectionFactory.class
  defining class javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory
BundleLoader[com.ibm.msg.client.osgi.jms.prereq_7.0.1.5] found local class javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory
```

IMHO, this has to do with the `org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation` setting and the fact that the 7.0.1.5 JMS prereq occurs before the 6.0.2.5 one.

**Can someone explains the Bundle Class Loader behaviour ?? Why do Equinox wires the bundle A this way ?? And how can I achieve the expected behaviour ??**

Bundle B is working as expected...

Answer (score 0):

Don't if this is a valid answer but try using this format when defining the dependency in BUndle A version="[7.0.1,7.0.1]" which denotes a strict version range. Also worse case if you're still having issues can you can you load the class directly from the Bundle by doing Platform.getBundle("com.ibm.msg.client.osgi.wmq").loadClass("com.myclass")?

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar situation when I use do OSGi related coding in IDE. This wiring done by your IDE, is wrong. It wires the class from `com.ibm.mq.osgi.client_6.0.2.5` while you expect it to wire the same class of `com.ibm.msg.client.osgi.wmq_7.0.1.5` . The same problem is happening when in the second issue you talked about. You can check this by finding `com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory` class where IDE using it. ( You can use Ctrl + Mouse click to see which version is wired ).